# PlayScape Publishing Kit version 1.11 - unity3D - crash in apk

Tags: android, playscape

It fails to deploy our game with the new SDK. When you start to crash apk.

Unity version: 4.6.5f1

Causes crash in native lib - libplayscape_pubkit.so:

```
Playscape.Analytics.Report.Instance.ReportLevelStarted ("level name", new Dictionary<string, double> 
{ 
        {"waveId", 0}, 
        {"levelTime", 0}, 
        {"remainingLives", 0}, 
        {"userTablets", 0}, 
        {"userDiamonds", 0}, 
        {"heroLevel", 0},
});
```

Error when starting the apk:

```
    7-20 19:29:42.926    4106-4121/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.aldagames.dyl-1/libplayscape_pubkit.so 0x41f94bd0
07-20 19:29:42.926    4106-4121/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.aldagames.dyl-1/libplayscape_pubkit.so' already loaded in same CL 0x41f94bd0 -- only notice
07-20 19:29:42.936    4106-4121/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x0000100a (code=-6), thread 4121 (UnityMain)
07-20 19:29:42.946    4106-4109/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 380K, 5% free 8268K/8696K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 23ms
07-20 19:29:42.986      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-20 19:29:42.986      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ Build fingerprint: 'google/nakasi/grouper:4.4.3/KTU84L/1148727:user/release-keys'
07-20 19:29:42.986      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ Revision: '0'
07-20 19:29:42.986      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ pid: 4106, tid: 4121, name: UnityMain  >>> com.aldagames.dyl <<<
07-20 19:29:42.986      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
07-20 19:29:43.106      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ r0 00000000  r1 00001019  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
07-20 19:29:43.106      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ r4 00000006  r5 00000016  r6 00001019  r7 0000010c
07-20 19:29:43.106      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ r8 7132ebd0  r9 3b9aca00  sl 00000001  fp 6c9aa07c
07-20 19:29:43.106      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ ip 6a415f78  sp 6c9aa000  lr 4025209d  pc 40261048  cpsr 000f0010
07-20 19:29:43.106      121-121/? I/DEBUG﹕ d0  6e2074727a696c61  d1
```

Comment: Did you get any errors while unity was making apk file? Could you provide some unity logs from console?

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue?

Comment: When making apk file we do not have any errors.
The problem was not solved.

Comment: I can send you the APK file.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4hreyKsT - complete log